# Executing javascript code after the asp: Button onClick handler?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

There is an asp: Button, in the onClientClick event, js-animation is started, in the onClick event on the server, a file is generated via response.Write () and response.End (). Can I somehow determine the end of the onClick event on the client to stop the animation?

Comment: There is no event on the client side - once the button is a clicked a postback occurs. Normally a fresh page is sent to the client. But if you're sending a file to the client, that's it. You can't send a file to the client and send some sort of action in the same response. You'll have to think of another way, such as executing the code on the client side *before* server side event.

Comment: thanks, i decided th use AJAX